# Is there a way to hide the running flex mobile application or change its name?

Tags: android, ios, apache-flex, mobile, flex4.5

I am working on a try-out app targeting ios and adroid mobile devices and I use flex 4.6. I want to hide the app in the list of running applications. Is it possible?

If not, is there a way to change the name and icon of the app in run-time after installation?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to change the app name and icon at runtime?

Comment: For what legitimate reason do you want to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to hide the app in the list of running applications. Is it possible?

In Android, no.

> If not, is there a way to change the name and icon of the app in run-time after installation?

In Android, no.